# Keep image same height as div

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to make this image the same height as the div container, I tried max-height, min-height normal height as auto and 100%. Nothing seems to be making the height the right size. I know with the image it wont look good but I just need it to fit.

here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/UkrdP/

img code -

```
.portfolioItem {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using JavaScript, the only way I could think of doing this off the top of my head is by explicitly setting the `height` property of `.item` to a certain amount of `px`, together with `height: 100%;` on `.portfolioItem`

EDIT:
As such: http://jsfiddle.net/3HP5A/

Answer (score 0):

exactly how it is.

```
.portfolioItem {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: That didn't appear to fix the OP's problem as far as I could see.